# Accessing a Spring Bean from a Servlet

Tags: spring

I have a Spring Bean defined in my applicationContext like:

```
<bean id="spaceReader" class="com.company.SpaceReader">
</bean>
```

I would like to be able to access this bean in my Application Servlet without having to use:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONTEXT_LOCATION);
context.getBean("SpaceReader");
```

I've tried exporting it using the following:

```
<bean id="ContextExporter" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
    <property name="contextExporterAttributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="SpaceReaderKey">
            <ref local="spaceReader" />
        </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but when i inject it into the Servlet, it returns a Null value.  Just wondering if there's something i'm missing when i export the Bean or when i try to access it in the Servlet?

Comment: Add the code showing how you are attempting to retrieve the bean from your servlet context.

Comment: spaceReader = (SpaceReader)getServletContext().getAttribute("SpaceReader");

Comment: Is it possible your code should be using the lowercase local ref?

spaceReader = (SpaceReader)getServletContext().getAttribute("spaceReader"); –

Answer (score 5):

You can inject dependencies using annotations even in servlet (there is a special `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` helper class for this pourpose):

```
public class CustomServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

   @Override
   public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
      super.init(config);
      // inject productService dependency
      SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
   }

   ....

}
```

Comment: thanks for your response and example, i tried that but i'm still getting a null value. I had it working earlier when i was getting the context using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext but ideally i'd like to inject the Bean into the Servlet.  Would it be possible i'm exporting it incorrectly from the Application Context? Thanks, O.

Comment: I am not familiar with `ServletContextAttributeExporter`, so I can't tell you. But I noticed a difference between exposed key `SpaceReaderKey` and one used in code `getServletContext().getAttribute("SpaceReader")`. May be it must be the same?